# Error "Sun.security.validator.ValidatorException" throwing when downloading the agent of the remote server via SSH tunnel using Jprofiler

Tags: java, ssh-keys, ssh-tunnel, jprofiler, java-security

I have established a SSH connection via Jprofiler to a remote server.  I have used the following configurations.

Tunnel mode : Direct SSH connection

Authentication : Password

Discover running JVMs and attach to selected process

Then, start to download the agent, I got the following error message. Please advise me to solve this problem.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the JRE cannot make an SSH connection to the download server, maybe you have a proxy in between?

There is a way to manually install the agent archive: Download

https://download.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/jprofiler_agent_linux-x86_11_0_1.tar.gz

replacing "11_0_1" with the installed JProfiler version and "linux-x86" with the platform of the remote machine and extract this file into your JProfiler installation. Note that the archive has a prefix directory "jprofiler11" that corresponds to the installation directory. Then the remote attach mechanism will not have to download the agent.